# doubts action bar, toolbar, etc

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

Well, I'm trying to make an app that needs to have some sort of ActionBar, which only have to schedule and design once, and then serve me for all my APP activity.
I'm not sure how this works, need a little guidance please.

To give you an idea of what I want, I would like something like this:

[image: example app]

A top, that is the general of the APP. And then below as well as a submenu with icons, with different options.

What exactly would have to use it? I've been tinkering with ActionBar but that it me for the top .. But to the other as you would?

Both want them to be static and are always in every activity of my APP, without having to copy and paste the code of each una..Que I guess and this somehow you are ready to embed it anywhere, programming only once.

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't really have much to do with Android. This is about how you can re-use code multiple places.

You could use inheritance for this purpose.

Say you have 3 different activities, but you want them to have a set of common features - in your case the `ActionBar`.

In that case you could create an `abstract class` that implements the `ActionBar` and make all your activities inherit from this `abstract class`.

The hierarchy could look something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.oncreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Setup your common ActionBar here.
    }
}
```

Now for this `abstract class` to do its work, you'll have to make all your activities inherit from this, like so:

```
public class MyActivityA extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.oncreate(savedInstanceState); // It's important to call through to super to have it setup the ActionBar for the current activity.
        // Next call setContentView(R.layout.my_activity_layout);
        // And what else you need to do.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_a_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And for the next `Activity` you do the same:

```
public class MyActivityB extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.oncreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Next call setContentView(R.layout.my_activity_layout);
        // And what else you need to do.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_b_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The `onCreateOptionsMenu` is implemented in all your activities, as to create different menu items and the same should go for your `onOptionsItemSelected`.

Now this is a very basic example of how to share basic features for multiple classes and it should be something you'd have to be knowledgable about ***before*** you start working with Android, as the above code is common Java.

Also keep in mind, that it's a very broad question you're asking.

I actually just wanted to put this in a comment, but decided it would become too large to fit into the comments.